# Tapped vs. Coupled Inductor

Tags: inductor, autotransformer

I have reverse engineered a sounder circuit which appears to be using a center tapped inductor. Since then, I have tried to find center tapped / 3-pin inductors and cannot find them from a reliable source, the only place I manage to find was from Huizhou Haicheng Electronics Factory on Alibaba, see below.

[image: three-pin inductor]

After some research, I have found that things such as auto-transformers or coupled inductors can also be used in sounder resonating circuits.
As I understand it, the difference between a center tapped inductor and a coupled inductor is that the CT is a single coil around a core with a wire 'tapped' at some point in the middle of the coil, and a coupled inductor is two separate coils sharing a common core, if the end of one of the coils is connected to the beginning of the next, this essentially, at least in my mind, makes a tapped inductor.
Now, it is very easy for me to source coupled inductors from reliable suppliers such as Mouser, Farnell, and RS, etc, so it is much more preferable if I would be able to use these as a replacement.

So the question is: **Can coupled inductors be used in place of a tapped inductor?**

If yes, what would the advantage be of using one over the other, other than the fact one is much easier to find?

Or am I way off the bat and they are two completely different things?

Thanks in advance.

---

*Side Question:

Would two inductors in series act similarly, or not due to the fact they do not have a common core like the above two components?*

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR : YES

You are right regarding the fact that connecting two coils of a coupled inductor (transformer) in serie makes a center tapped inductor (autotransformer).

(the words in the parenthesis are the generic terms, while the ones you use are more specific to sound/signal processing)